# Accessing iframe DOM

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, onresize

I want to stop YouTube playback onresize

i have an iframe

```
  <iframe id="tutube" class="youTubeVideo" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" allowscriptaccess="always"
    src="https://youtube.com/embed/d3cRXJ6Ww44?showinfo=0&autohide=1&enablejsapi=1">
  </iframe>
```

and a function

```
function stopTheVideo(){
    var div = document.getElementById("tutube");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    div.style.display = state == 'hide' ? 'none' : '';
    func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
            };
```

which I call

```
<body onresize="stopTheVideo();"
```

and I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefinedindex10.html:198 toggleVideoindex10.html:206 resizeFunctionsindex10.html:31 onresize
```

Any ideas?

Comment: well, if i set var state = 'hide', it does work here on FF37 and Chrome 41

Comment: I just pasted it in a fresh html file, tested on chrome, ff and safari. Doesnt work

Comment: Safari 7.1.3 works too for me on mavericks. No error thrown. Note I also added a `<div id="tutube">`.

Comment: ah, I had given the iframe that ID

Comment: no it is its container, but you could access it via `var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;` if it is the only iframe element in the page

Comment: @Kaiido note that im trying to stop the video ?

Comment: hard refresh your browser (clear cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your code expects that your `<iframe>` is wrapped inside another element with an `id="tutube"`. `getElementsByTagName()` won't pick the element on which it has been called even if it matches.

So you could either refactor your HTML so that it matches the expectations of your JS:

```js
<body onresize="stopTheVideo();">
  <div id="tutube">
    <iframe class="youTubeVideo" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" allowscriptaccess="always"
      src="https://youtube.com/embed/d3cRXJ6Ww44?showinfo=0&autohide=1&enablejsapi=1">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <script>
    var state= 'hide';
    function stopTheVideo(){
      var div = document.getElementById("tutube");
      var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
      div.style.display = (state == 'hide') ? 'none' : '';
      func = (state == 'hide') ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
      iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Either rewrite your JS so that it works with your HTML:

```js
function stopTheVideo(){
  var iframe = document.getElementById("tutube").contentWindow;
  div.style.display = state == 'hide' ? 'none' : '';
  func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
  iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
};
```

Comment: but then it disappears. It's supposed to stay

Comment: no, you set the display to none, so it disappears. If you want to show on next call, set your `state`var to something else than `'hide'` when hiding

Comment: yes, remove this line : `div.style.display = (state == 'hide') ? 'none' : '';`

Comment: I didn't get quite get that. Does `hide` have special meaning ??

Comment: state is a boolean, by updating its value, you can either decide that your function will hide the iframe and stop the video (first case after the `?` in your function) or to show and play (second case, after the `:`)